# MVC3 Ajax link confirmation dialog using jquery-ui dialog box

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have been learning MVC 3 recently and I have found two solutions to deleting records from my list view. However I would like components of both of them, but my lack of knowledge in javascript is making this very difficult.

I have these two links for deleting:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", 
    new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "delete-link" }) |
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete Ajax", "Delete", "MyController",
    new {id = item.ID},
    new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnBegin = "return ConfirmDone()",
        OnSuccess = "deleteConfirmation"
    })
```

The first one uses the following javascript to delete the record:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var deleteLinkObj;
        // delete Link
        $('.delete-link').click(function () {
            deleteLinkObj = $(this);  
            $('#delete-dialog').dialog('open');
            return false; 
        });

        //definition of the delete dialog.
        $('#delete-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false, width: 400, resizable: false, modal: true, 
            buttons: {
                "Continue": function () {
                    $.post(deleteLinkObj[0].href, function (data) 
                    {  
                        var rowId = "#myTableItem-id-" + data.id;
                        $('.myTable').find(rowId).hide('slow');
                    });

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The second link uses this script function for confirmation:

```
<script>
    function ConfirmDone() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want delete this item?");
    }
</script>
```

Now both of these solutions work fine, however I prefer the coding of the second link, but I like the confirmation box that jquery-ui produces in the first link. So I would like to blend them together.

What I think I need to do is when the `Ajax.ActionLink` calles the `ConfirmDone()` then I need to show a jquery dialog as I do with the first link. However I am unsure how to produce this and allow this dialog to return a true or false depending on the button that is pressed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of trying things out I have came up with a solution:

My link changed to this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "StruContractUser",
     new { id = item.UserID },
     new AjaxOptions {
         HttpMethod = "Delete",
         OnBegin = "JSONDeleteFile_OnBegin",
         OnComplete = "notify"
     },
new { @class = "delete-link" })
```

Which calls this function with the `OnBegin` option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function JSONDeleteFile_OnBegin(context) {
        return false; 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you mean returning `false` does not show default confirm dialog and shows jquery dialog that you want